# Linux log file monitoring by zabbix 2.2.1

Tags: zabbix

Windows monitoring the log files, have no problem. But I could not watch the log file in linux. I wonder where I make mistakes.

Zabbix Version : 2.2.1
Linux : Centosx64

ActiveCheck

### Item

> log["/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log","error"]

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? See my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/1106534/437093

Answer (score -1):

Leave quotes out:

```
log[/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log,error]
```